# Css grid paragraph overflows

Tags: css, overflow, css-grid

Hi I am trying to fit my text grif items but if the text is big enough it overflows out of grid.
How can I make grid items height flexible and contain all of the divs text

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/TyphooNN/z92cbwjt/13/)

```css
.grid{
  display     : grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) ;
  background  : red;
  white-space : nowrap;
  }
.item{
  font-size : 30px;   
  border    : 1px green solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">
  
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  sdfsd
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  sdfsdf
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  sergey1sergey2sergey3sergey4sergey5sergey6sergey7sergey8sergey9sergeys10ergey11sergey12
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  sdfsf
  </div>
  <div class="item">
sdsdfsd
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  sdfsdf
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CSS property `word-break: break-word;`
and remove the `white-space: nowrap;` from the parent container.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr);
  background: red;
}

.item {
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px green solid;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">

  </div>
  <div class="item">
    sdfsd
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    sdfsdf
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    sergey1sergey2sergey3sergey4sergey5sergey6sergey7sergey8sergey9sergeys10ergey11sergey12
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    sdfsf
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    sdsdfsd
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    sdfsdf
  </div>
</div>
```